# A question on decreasing function

Tags: differential-calculus, calculus-of-functors

Let $t\in (0,1)$ and

- ${a_n}{x^n} + .... + {a_1}{x^1} + f(t) = 0$
- $f(t) $ is continuous decreasing function of $t$.
- $a_i\ge0$ for all $i$.
- $y(t)$ is positive real zero of the first  equition.

Can we say that $y(t)$ is continuous **decreasing** function of $t$?

Comment: Which zero? In any case, the answer is no.

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev - I edited this post.

Comment: You may well consider the dependence on $s$ of the solutions to $\sum a_kx^k+s=0$. Assuming you have an isolated positive root, its location will be a differentiable function of $s$ in a small neighborhood. You will be able to see the sign of its derivative from the usual chain rule. Then it's just a matter of precomposing with $f(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample:  Let $n=1, a_1 = 1, f(t) = -t$.

Then $y(t) = t$ which is a continuous **increasing** function of $t$.

Did you mean to say **increasing**?  Because in that case, the conjecture is true in intervals where $y(t)$ is strictly greater than zero.

Comment: The conjecture is never true. Take your favorite polynomial p(x) with at least one extremum and let $f(t)=t$ or $-t$, whichever fits the conjecture. As is obvious from the graph, there would be both increasing and decreasing branches. One *might* be able to say something about the minimal/maximal root (and then, obviously, it suffices to consider the case $f(t)=\pm t$).

Comment: Ah, but the problem states that all $a_i > 0$.  So there will not be an extremum at any  $x>0$.

Comment: Oops! Sorry. Then one of them is certainly true (probably, yours), and it seems sufficient to consider $f(t)=t$.